# Null pointer Exception in android while selecting brand name

Tags: android

I am getting NPE when I select brand name when passing brand name to model. Based on brand names I want to display model names. For that created hashmap in that key is the brand name and values are the list of models.

can any one help me? modellist was showing 2216 but that actual list is 22

**logcat**

```
 java.lang.NullPointerException
            at info.androidhive.slidingmenu.HomeFragment$12.onItemClick(HomeFragment.java:454)
```

**updated java**

```
private void getBrandModel()
    {


        String url = URLBuilder.getBrandUrl();
        String json = JSONBuilder.getJSONOwnViewStock("", "");
        SendToServerTask1 task = new SendToServerTask1(getActivity());
        task.execute(url, json);


    }
    private void SetBrandModel(String json)


    {

        try
        {


            ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();

            BrandModelResult result_object = objectMapper.readValue(json, BrandModelResult.class);

            String brandmodel_result = result_object.getRESULT();

            Log.d("lead_result","" + brandmodel_result);
            brands=result_object.getBRANDS();


            Log.i("brands", "" + brands);
            int length=result_object.getBRANDS().size();


            if (brandmodel_result.equals("SUCCESS")) {

                for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {



                }
                for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {

                    brandList.add(brands.get(i).getBRANDNAME());
                    List<BrandModelResult.Models> modelsList = result_object.getBRANDS().get(i).getMODELS();
                    //modelList = new ArrayList<>();
                    for (int j = 0; j < modelsList.size() ; j++) {
                        modelList.add(modelsList.get(j).getMODELNAME());
                    }

                    brandModelListMap.put(brands.get(i).getBRANDNAME(),modelList);

                    Log.i("Model List", "" + modelList);
                }


            }

            else
            {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "Unable to load data please try again", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        // When we click brand AutocompleteTextView
       brand.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
            selectedBrand = arg0.getItemAtPosition(arg2).toString();
            List<BrandModelResult.Models> modelsList = result_object.getBRANDS().get(arg2).getMODELS();

            List<String> modelkeys = brandModelListMap.get(selectedBrand);
            if (modelkeys != null) {


                modelList.add(modelsList.get(arg2).getMODELNAME());

            }









                model.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

                    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
                        selectedModel = arg0.getItemAtPosition(arg2).toString();
                        //modelID = modelIDs[arg2];
                        ArrayAdapter adapterSearch1 = new ArrayAdapter(getActivity().getBaseContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, modelList);
                        model.setAdapter(adapterSearch1);
                        model.setThreshold(0);


                    }
                });
                // If there is not model for a brand

                if (brandList.equals("0")) {

                    // Show alert dialog when there is no model for a brand

                    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
                    alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("");
                    alertDialogBuilder
                            .setMessage("There is no model for this brand")
                            .setCancelable(false)
                            .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                    dialog.dismiss();
                                }
                            });
                    AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();
                    alertDialog.show();

                } else
                // Show model list in the model Edit Text if a Brand has model
                {

                }

                // When we click on the Brand Edit Text, this is triggered to send request to get model JSON <over>
                //////////////////////////////////////////////////////
            }
        });

        ArrayAdapter adapterSearch = new ArrayAdapter(getActivity().getBaseContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, brandList);
        brand.setAdapter(adapterSearch);
        brand.setThreshold(0);

        brand.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                brand.showDropDown();
            }
        });
        brand1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                brand1.showDropDown();
            }
        });
        model.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {


                model.showDropDown();
            }
        });
        model1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                model1.showDropDown();
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: line numbers would help ;) in which line the NPE appears?

Comment: List<String> modelkeys = brandModelListMap.get(brands.get(arg2).getBRANDNAME()); this line

Comment: Set a breakpoint on this line and check the values of ``brandModelListMap ``, ``brands``, ``brands.get(arg2)`` and ``brands.get(arg2).getBRANDNAME()`` and you will find out which value is null

Comment: cursor is not going inside

Comment: do you debug the current version of your app? if the cursor does not go inside there wouldn't be a NPE ;)

Comment: arg2 2 and size 2125

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89792/discussion-between-care567-and-finki).